# List of yyyymm format dates of last 3 months for a given date 2019-12-31

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a list of dates in the format of `yyyymm` of the past 3 months

For the given input_date unknown datatype

```
Input_date = 2019-12-31
```

Required output

```
201912
201911
210910
```

Numeric values

I want to use the solution query as a sub query of another query

```
Select * from table where fyr_actg_prd in 
(select to_number(to_char(add_months(to_date(input_date,'yyyy-mm-dd'),1-LEVEL), 'yyyymm')) from dual connect by LEVEL <=3)
```

The above query when acted it is giving

```
Select * from table where fyr_actg_prd in 
    (select to_number(to_char(add_months(to_date(2019-12-31,'yyyy-mm-dd'),1-LEVEL), 'yyyymm')) from dual connect by LEVEL <=3)
```

Fyr_actg_prd is numeric datatype

THE PROBLEM WITH THE ABOVE SOLUTION IS  the input_date is without single quotes so error

Comment: What is the datatype of column `input_date`?

Comment: I want to use the solution query as sub query in another query  . Such that select * from table where fyr_actg_prd in (solution query )

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(:INPUT_DATE,-LEVEL+1),'YYYYMM') FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_months()` function within a query containing `connect by level <= 3` :

```
with t as
(
 select date'2019-12-31' as input_date
   from dual     
)
select to_char( add_months(input_date, 1 - level ) , 'yyyymm' ) as months
  from t
 connect by level <=  3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6706ac16c8c48db938815443a145abf9)</kbd>

Comment: This fails to iterate when the `input_date` is in January or February [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d86f8bbb026fe799792047541b34a7d6)

Comment: of course @MT0 , I just replied what OP needed. He already stays within one year only.

Comment: The requirement to "stay within one year only" is not mentioned in the question (including edit history) or any comments.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan   i am getting input as 2019-12-31 without single quotes

Comment: If input_date is a date datatype . It is not coming with single quotes .

Comment: If it is not coming with single quotes either it is a date or number . Should we convert it into char then into date

Comment: `date'2019-12-31'` is just your column value of type date within your table. To be able to extract year and month parts of the dates we need `yyyymm` format @amarenderreddyjali . Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7b4279a41f68edc05b9952f59882a62b)

Comment: @amarenderreddyjali  where did you extract input_date, from a table's column, from a file, from a PL/SQL block ...? It should have a data type ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't generate all the values, just use `BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  fyr_actg_prd BETWEEN TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( :input_date, -2 ), 'YYYYMM' )
                    AND     TO_CHAR( :input_date, 'YYYYMM' )
```

If you want to generate values you can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  fyr_actg_prd IN (
  SELECT TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( :input_date, LEVEL - 3 ), 'YYYYMM' )
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
);
```

or a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH months ( month, idx ) AS (
  SELECT TO_CHAR( :input_date, 'YYYYMM' ),
         1
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( :input_date, -idx ), 'YYYYMM' ),
         idx + 1
  FROM   months
  WHERE  idx < 2
)
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  fyr_actg_prd IN ( SELECT month FROM months );
```

Comment: Doesn't ur hierarchical query does not need connect by clause